# HTML/CSS subtleties: How do I place "pins" on a resizeable "map"?

Tags: css, html, resize, css-position

Don't be intimidated by the length of this post! (I've just copied the code from jsfiddle)

I'm trying to fix "pins" on an image ("map") that fits all screen-sizes without becoming distorted (i.e. max-height and max-width are 100%) and I've managed to get the pins somewhat fixed. However, although the following code(in the jsfiddle) looks like it works for some sizes, the pins slowly move away from their place as the dimensions of the window change. Have a look: (if you don't see the change in the fiddle itself, you can try copying and pasting the code onto a text-editor and then opening it on a browser. Resize the browser to a long-narrow-strip or a wide-narrow-strip and you'll see what I mean):

http://jsfiddle.net/bKbWf/

Thanks to anyone who can help solve this.

The code (same as the stuff on the above jsfiddle) is posted below:
(HTML):

```
<div class="mapNpins"> <!--map and pins begin here-->
    <div class="map-container"><img class ="map" src="http://www.placekitten.com/1024/635"/>
        <ul class = "ulist">
            <li class="pin1"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philadelphia"><img src="http://www.placekitten.com/20/20"></a></li>
                <li class="pin2"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston"><img src="http://www.placekitten.com/20/20"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- map and pins end here -->
</div>
```

(CSS):

```
.mapNpins { /*can be used to  manipulate/position the entire mapNpins block*/
display: block; 
border: 2px solid red;}

.map-container {
position: relative; /*this is so that later each list-element
    (i.e. pin) can be positioned with respect to the map-picture
        (i.e. the pins will be able to move/resize with the map)*/
text-align: center; /*centers map horizontally*/}

.map{
padding-left: 0.7%; /*misc. image correction*/
max-width: 100%; /* map image resizes with screen*/ 
max-height: 100%;/* map image resizes with screen*/}

.ulist {
list-style: none; /*to remove the bullets*/}

.ulist li a {
display: block;
position: absolute; /*allows each list-element to be controlled
         individually, but all with respect to .map-container (which
            is the first parent that has pos-relative)*/}


/*positioning the pins*/
.map-container .ulist .pin1 a {
text-align: center; 
border: 2px solid orange; /*border color only for recognition*/
left: 25%; top:37%;}

.map-container .ulist .pin2 a {
border: 2px solid blue; /*border color only for recognition*/
left: 35%; top:47%;}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If your post is this long, don't worry. There are *much* longer posts out there.

Comment: Hahaha, I guess that first line belied my naivete, didn't it? Thanks for the welcome (it's just that I was hoping people who might know the answer don't simply go away because they don't have time to answer it)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a jquery for loop:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
    for(i = 1; i <= 2000; i++) {
    if($(window).width() === i) {
        // set the css due to the ratio
        $('.pin1').css('margin-left', ($('.pin1').css('margin-left') + i));
    }
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried it, but it still gives the same result. I think the problem is that the position of the pins depend on the size of the _image_, not the window (the image in turn follows the _size_ of the browser-window, but always maintains it's original aspect ratio so that it doesn't look distorted). I just don't know how to fix the pins to the image... Thanks for your help though (it always feels good to see someone's answered!).

Comment: The for loop I supplied were not exact measurements where I `put set css due to the ratio` I meant you change what I put to what you want